# How to fix Tree conflict issue in SVN

Tags: svn

I am new to SVN.

I found a conflict message as shown below:

```
rahulv@SWS306:~/sp/s2$ svn status
M       Gemfile
M       Gemfile.lock
M       config/intializers/secret_token.rb
D     C tmp
      >   local dir unversioned, incoming dir add upon update
D       tmp/cache
?       tmp/data
D       tmp/pids
D       tmp/sessions
D       tmp/sockets
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
rahulv@SWS306:~/sp/s2$
```

The issue occurred after updating using 'svn up' command.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: @bahrep, oops, my mistake then. I thought most Rails people use git rather than svn.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985504/svn-how-to-resolve-local-add-incoming-add-upon-update-on-a-folder

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this issue today, and because I didn't want keep the current contents of the new versioned directory, simple solution was:

```
svn status      # review current situation
svn revert tmp  # fix, replace tmp with right path for you
svn status      # verify there are no conflicts any more
```

Of course, if there's any doubt that the existing non-versioned directory contains anything valuable, copy that elsewhere first (and then possibly add to SVN after reverting, if those files should be under version control).

Comment: great answer, but I want to keep the incoming changes. Any idea how to do the opposite and override the local file?

Comment: @SM3RKY What do you mean? This will overwrite any local changes (which is why I suggest copying anything valuable elsewhere). The usual svn update should then get the version you want, as usual.

Answer (score 5):

The error message in the status output says it all:

```
> local dir unversioned, incoming dir add upon update
```

That means that you had a `tmp` directory created in your working copy using `mkdir` but did *not* add it to the repository (yet), although you probably already added it *locally* using `svn add`. When running `svn update`, from the repository a different `tmp` directory is checked out, which will overwrite your `tmp` directory unless you fix this issue.

As a rule of thumb, try not to work on the same parts of a project in a single branch/trunk with other people, as this will eventually cause merge conflict headaches of unheard proportions.

The following SVNBook chapters are a must read:

- ["Dealing with Structural Conflicts"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html),
- ["Resolve Any Conflicts"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve).